# Terminanl removes characters that should not be deleted

Tags: terminal

I have a problem with terminal. When I use language different from English I can delete static characters.[image]

Comment: Do you have unescaped non-printing sequences in your `PS1`?

Comment: I also don't see where non-English plays into this. Where do you "use" the language?

Comment: @BenjaminW. No, I dont. In first row I wrote russian at first and then delete russian and static chars

Comment: I see you've also asked in the Alacritty GitHub – does look like a bug indeed.

Comment: @BenjaminW.I asked everywhere ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in [locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale). I set it and now terminal works correct.